# Calculating of the sum

Tags: combinatorics

I'm trying to found this sum:$\sum_{i=0}^m\left(\begin{array}{cccc}m\\i\end{array}\right)\cdot (-1)^i\cdot i^m$. I calculated this sum for small value of $m$ and realized that it's equal to $(-1)^mm!$. How can that be proved?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: What is $n$? There is no $n$ in the sum!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint:* Start with the well-known [binomial formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) $(1-x)^m=\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^m{m\choose i}(-x)^i$, then differentiate both sides, and see what happens. Then multiply both sides with *x*, and differentiate both yet again. Do you see a pattern forming ? :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to prove your assumption by induction, though the user above me right.